# What's the difference in this javascript assignment?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What the difference between these two assignments?

```js
this.list.push(...response.data);

//vs

this.list = [].concat(this.list, response.data);
```

Comment: The 1st adds the items to the existing `this.list`. The 2nd combines  `this.list` and `response.data` to a new array, and assigns the result to `this.list`.

Comment: Is `this.list` declared as an array to begin with?  Have you ran each line?  Do they create the same output?  Is there an actual issue or problem you are trying to solve or are you just curious?

Comment: yes, this.list is an array

Comment: For more reference, compare [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: I jsut wasn't sure about the 3 dots

Comment: It's called the "spread operator" (also called the "splat operator" in other languages) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: hi rocket, yes, I have a problem. When I load objects into this array and then the data gets rendered into a vue table my memory footprint skyrockets by about 30Mb each time I do it. The page fetches the data with an infiniate loading and after the fifth or so fetch it blows out the memory. I'm thinking it might be the Vue table that is doing a bunch of stuff under the hood to allocate memory because the amount of data I'm fetching is small. ~10kb or less per fetch

Comment: Why are you using `[].concat(this.list, response.data)` instead of `this.list.concat(response.data)`?

Comment: @user1186050 I guess you are trying to load too much data at once.  That sounds like it should be its own question, though.

Comment: but the data I'm fetching is small. ~80 kb, then as soon as I get the data and concat it, Vue renders/adds the data into the v-data-table. But when I do this the memory blows up like 30Mb each time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer:

**The first example:**

```
this.list.push(...response.data);
```

The example mutates the data using `push`. This means that the Array is altered in place. This is considered **"impure"** as it does not return a **new** Object - it changes data that already exists.

---

**The second example:**

```
this.list = [].concat(this.list, response.data);
```

This example returns a **new** Array Object. This means that it subscribes to the functional paradigm. It is considered **pure** because it does not alter the existing Array, it creates a new one for the occasion.

---

### Is that all?

Right now you might be thinking "***That's what the other answers said!***"

You're right. I initially was just going to write an addendum, but I thought I might as well provide all of the information succinctly. The first part of the answer seems like a rehash, because they were correct, and...well, you can't beat that. However,
***here's what they missed***:

---

### Additional Differences:

If you were to look inside of `concat` you would see that the method itself checks to see if `Symbol.isConcatSpreadable` is true or false. This might lead you to believe that if `spreadable` is *true* (which it is by default in `Array` Objects)that they perform the same way. This is not true at all.

While internally the `spread operator` utilizes the elements `@@iterator` to combine arrays/values, the `Array.prototype.concat` method is built, literally, like a for loop, a.e. `i=0;i<len;i++;` - As a matter of fact as the array is being combined it's actually popping the first element off of the called array and performing assertions and tests that are otherwise unnecessary when utilizing `spread`.

### **Okay, Okay, but what does that mean?**

Well, it means that the two examples above can have drastically different results if you somehow adjust the iterator and think you're concatenating Arrays with the `spread` operator. The results will *not* be what you expect.

This can be seen quite easily in the below:

```js
let a = ["a","b","c"];
let b = ["d","e","f"];

b[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
};

let c = JSON.stringify([].concat(a, b));
let d = JSON.stringify((a.push(...b), a));

console.log(c, d);
// a,b,c,d,e,f
// a,b,c,1,2,3
```

This also means that, **unlike** the `Array.prototype.concat` method, because spread uses an `iterator` and that iterator can be supplied/adjusted manually **and** that iterator can be **async** - it opens up the potential for uses that `concat` was never designed for.

Basically, `spread` is a more well-rounded operator with allowances for many different use cases, whereas `concat` is literally just a simple "Take *this* and put it over *there*" with a `spreadable` check that just determines whether it should perform a mini for loop of values inside it's larger for loop, or if the inner-array references are good enough.

---

I hope this answers your question and gives you further insight into the operations and what's actually happening under the hood!

***Happy Coding!***

Answer (score 5):

The result will be the **same in terms of content**.
The items contained in `response.data` will by appended to `this.list`.

However, with `this.list.push(...response.data)`, the list stays the same and is simply expanded with the new items, so the list is modified in place. Any reference to that list will see the change happen.

With `[].concat(this.list, response.data)`, a new list is created. This new list is the concatenation of both list and is then reassigned to `this.list`. So after the assignment `this.list` points to a new list. Any reference to the old list won't see the change happen in this case.

Comment: Sorry, havn't seen you already answered while I was answering. Upvoted yours because you've been faster and the answer is correct :)

Comment: @David, no worries! Two explanations are better than one!

Comment: good answer! Just to let you know, I did upvote and add another answer. Not because you were wrong, but because there were a few things that I thought you had missed :)

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

The first one is impure, the second one is pure (although it looks like it is done in an already impure context).

**Explanation**

If you use `.push`, the `Array` on which `.push` is called get's altered, because `.push` adds an item *to the end of the existing `Array`*.

`.concat` instead create *a new `Array`* and appends the other `Array`s *to the new `Array`*. This way, the original `Array`s aren't altered.

Comment: good answer! Just to let you know, I did upvote and add another answer. Not because you were wrong, but because there were a few things that I thought you had missed :)